# How to find generator matrix from the lexicographic parity-check matrix of a hamming code?

Tags: coding-theory

How to find generator matrix from the lexicographic parity-check matrix of a hamming code?

And also how to make it (by row operations) in a way that all columns of weight one are included in it?

For example for $[7,4]$Hamming code with Parity-check matrix:
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0&0&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the desired generator matrix is:

$$
G = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &    0&     0     &0     &0     &1     &1\\
     0     &1     &1     &0     &0     &1     &1\\
     0     &0     &1     &1     &0     &0     &1\\
     0     &0     &1     &0     &1     &1     &0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the single-weight columns are columns 1, 2, 4, and 5

Comment: Usually there is no such thing as *the* generator matrix. Any matrix with the right row space will do. And if you have a generator matrix taking it to reduced row echelon form will produce the weight one columns, won't it?

Comment: The simplest passage from a parity check matrix to a generator matrix (and back) is that if $H=(I|A)$ in block form, then $G=(A^T|I)$ or vice versa. Here you cannot bring $H$ to that form by elementary row operations unless you first (temporarily) shuffle the columns a bit. Alternatively, you can build that $I$-"block" from non-consecutive columns.